# Can "のたもうて" be the て−form of のたもう?

Tags: translation, て-form, old-japanese

I just learned that the て/た form of the verb たまう can be たまうて/たまうた. Is this the same for the verb のたもう? I am trying to translate a song and this て construction seems to appear in it. If this is the case, does "のたもうております" just mean "saying"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can say it as "のたまって" too.